# Width and height have no effect on <use> when referencing inline images

Tags: svg

I'm trying to inline some images into an SVG that uses `xlink:href` references pointed to fully qualified local paths.  For reasons why see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mingrammer/diagrams/issues/26#issuecomment-1359474330).  The example python does a reasonable job, but it will inline the same image many times in a single SVG which is not optimal.

So I tried a similar approach that converts something like this:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<image x="0" y="-144" width="101px" height="101px" xlink:href="/path/to/file.png" />
<image x="0" y="-144" width="101px" height="101px" xlink:href="/path/to/file.png" />
</svg>
```

To this

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
    <image id="file.png_1" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA..." />
</defs>
<use x="0" y="+144" width="101px" height="101px" href="#file.png_1" />
<use x="0" y="-144" width="101px" height="101px" href="#file.png_1" />
</svg>
```

### The problem

The way this renders (Safari and Chrome), it seems that `width` and `height` have no effect on the `<use>`.

I can get the desired result to render identically to the original if I move the `width` and `height` onto the `<defs><image/></defs>`.  But doing this makes the assumption that no SVG will EVER use the same image twice with different sizes.

Despite reading the SVG 1.1 Standard, I'm still no further forward on understanding how to size a `<use>` element without explicitly sizing it on the referenced `<image>` element.

Comment: Put the image in a symbol with a viewBox attribute and use the symbol

Comment: @enxaneta could you show a very short worked example as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment the OP is asking for an example:

> @enxaneta could you show a very short worked example as an answer.

In the next example I'm putting an image in a symbol. The image has a width and a height. Also the symbol has a viewBox. In this case the viewBox of the symbol has the same size as the image.

I'm using the symbol with use.The use element has a x and y attributes for the upper left corner. Also the use has a width and a height. Please observe that I'm preserving the same aspect ratio as the symbol's viewBox.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 65 50">
<symbol id="i" viewBox="0 0 22 9.8">
  <image  width="22" height="9.8" href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/bone300.svg"/>
</symbol>
<use href="#i" x="10" y="7" width="44" height="19.6" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseElement) width and height are ignored on a use element unless that use element points to a symbol or an svg element.

> The width and height properties on the ‘use’ element override the values for the corresponding properties on a referenced ‘svg’ or ‘symbol’ element when determining the used value for that property on the instance root element.

So wrapping the image in a symbol element and then pointing the use to the symbol should work.

Comment: Without seeing a worked example it's hard for me to say "this doesn't work". But the Naive interpretation of this just crops the image, it doesn't scale it. `<defs><symbol id="foo"><image href="..."></symbol></defs><use href="#foo" width="50px" height="50px" />`.  Also when you say "the specification says...".  Your quote doesn't mention anything being ignored.  Are you saying it's ignored because the specification only applies to `svg` and `symbol`?

Comment: Correct width and height is ignored except for symbol and svg elements is what the specification says and what browsers implement. In fact I'm actually the implementer of that code in Firefox. If you don't want cropping, use a viewBox.

Comment: Forgive my persistence, without seeing an example I'm doing a lot of guessing here (I'm new generally to SVGs). Setting a view box with arbitrary (square) dimensions and the image to `width="100%" height="100%"` works for square images. It seems to mess up scaling for non-square images.  I _guess_ because the viewBox loses the original aspect ratio of the underlying image.  Any thoughts on whether it's possible to work around this in the SVG, or will I need to interrogate the original image to discover its aspect ratio?

Comment: And how can I tell if the stub displays it as you really want. Please provide an actual [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You want an example, then meet me half way and provide the data from which to construct it.

Comment: Sadly I can't share proprietary images here. Perhaps do the tinyist google search for any small non-square png for experimentation to test?  That can be swapped with the stub in answer.  That way neither of us have to open-source anything we don't own.  I'm not trying to be obosternate here I just can't publish my images under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0)

Comment: Sure, please do that google search and find something you think is appropriate.